# NameError: global name "total" is not defined, but it is

Tags: python, variables, global

Every time I run my code, it tells me that total is not defined. I have it defined in support.py, which is then imported into stopping.py. I've looked for similar cases, but I can't see why it's telling me this. Please help!

This is stopping.py

```
from support import *

def main():

    def get_info():
      amplitude = float(input("Amplitude of the sine wave (in feet): "))
      period = float(input("Period of the sine wave (in feet): "))
      sign = float(input("Distance to the stop sign (in feet): "))
      nobrake = float(input("Distance needed to stop without using hand brakes (in feet): "))
      step = 9
      return amplitude, period, sign, nobrake

    get_info()

    get_distance(0, 0, 155.3, 134.71)

    print("Distance to the stop sign (in feet): 155.3")
    print("Distance needed to stop without using hand brakes (in feet): 350.5")
    print("Length of the sine wave: ", total)

main()
```

This is support.py

```
import math

def get_sine_length(amplitude, period, x_distance, step):
  x = 0.0
  total = 0.0
  last_x = 0
  last_y = 0
  while x <= x_distance + (step / 2):
     y = math.sin(2 * math.pi / period * x) * amplitude
     dist = get_distance(last_x, last_y, x, y)
     #print("distance from (", last_x, ",", last_y, ") to (", x, ",", y, ") is", dist)
     total = total + dist
     last_x = x
     last_y = y
     x = x + step
 return total

def get_distance(a, b, c, d):
   dx = c - a
   dy = d - b
   dsquared = dx**2 + dy**2
   result = math.sqrt(dsquared)
```

Comment: Post the actual exception so we can see when it occurs.

Comment: in support.py, `total` is a local variable

Comment: Where is `get_sine_length()` called after all?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`total` is local to `get_sine_length`. Since you're returning it, to get to it you call `get_sine_length` and store the result.

The problem doesn't actually have anything to do with the `import` really. It would be the same if the function definition for `get_sine_length` was in `stopping.py`. Variables defined inside functions (inside a `def someFunc():`) are only accessible to that function unless you force them to be global. Most of the time, however, you *shouldn't declare global variables just to access normally local vars from outside a function* - that is what returning is for.

This example shows the general issue you're running into. I'm hesitant to call it a problem, because it is actually an important language feature of python (and many other programming languages).

```
>>> def func():
...     localVar = "I disappear as soon as func() is finished running."
... 
>>> print localVar
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'localVar' is not defined
>>> func()
>>> print localVar
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'localVar' is not defined
```

Think of a function as a machine that takes in certain inputs and outputs others. You generally don't want to open up the machine- you just want to put the inputs in and get the output.

Comment: Even though I've imported support.py into stopping.py? Would I just define total as global to make it work?

Comment: Did any of my edits help? Although it would work, don't make `total` a global variable; instead, run `get_sine_length` and capture the result in a variable.